# I can't input after running command in docker, but I can if I execute it manually

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file for starting a Terraria server, but after starting the server, I can't input any commands. If I start the server directly in my shell, I am able to input commands. How can I get the same result in docker as if I had run the command myself in a shell?

This is the **desired behavior**, which is what happens when I run it from my shell:

```
$ TerrariaServerVolume/TerrariaServer -pass xxx -port 7777 -world ~/absolute/path/TerrariaWorldsVolume/testWorldName.wld
Terraria Server v1.4.2.2

Listening on port 7777
Type 'help' for a list of commands.

: Server started
help                      // my input
Available commands:
...                       //list of commands
: %                       //I pressed Ctrl+c
$
```

This is **what actually happens** in my docker container:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up
Terraria Server v1.4.2.2
TerrariaServer_1  | 
TerrariaServer_1  | Listening on port 7777
TerrariaServer_1  | Type 'help' for a list of commands.
TerrariaServer_1  | 
TerrariaServer_1  | : Server started
^[[6;23
```

I don't know what ^[[6;23 is, but then here's me trying to input commands:

```
...
TerrariaServer_1  | : Server started
^[[6;23Rhelp
help
exit
stop
ljadgkljasdgl
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping terraria_TerrariaServer_1 ... done
$
```

This is my setup:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  TerrariaServer:
    image: "mono:6.8.0.96-slim"
    ports:
      - 7777:7777
    expose:
      - 7777
    volumes:
      - "./TerrariaServerVolume:/Terraria/Server"
      - "./TerrariaWorldsVolume:/Terraria/Worlds"
    environment:
      - WorldName=testWorldName.wld
    command: bash -c "/Terraria/Server/TerrariaServer -pass <password> -port 7777 -world /Terraria/Worlds/$WorldName"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To type other commands after running docker-compose You need to use `-d` parameter.

Example:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

From docs:

> -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background, print new container names.